# Angular Resolver data prefetching for same route with different route parameters

Tags: angular, angular7

I am trying to grasp a concept about Angular Route Resolvers.

I want to introduce a Resolver which will prefetch the data for let's say products(by given id) before displaying them and their related component. For brevity, I am gonna use the following URL pattern:
`products/:id`.

I implement the `Resolve<T>` interface. The thing is, in the `resolve` method, as stated here: [Resolve Interface @ Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) we get as parameter `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` which is like the name states - a snapshot of the URL and its parameters at the stage of the first request. However, how are changes to route parameters(in our case `id`) reflected if we navigate to the same route but with different id. How the Resolver knows to update it's `data` property with the new product data without subscribing to any changes in the param data, considering we're using `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` instead of `ActivatedRoute`? Am I missing something?

Comment: Since you will be using either router.navigate or routerlink with different params to navigate to that particular route, Angular will consider that as a new route. As a result, the resolver will get called once again and you can get the params in the resolver method.

Comment: @Indragith Will it? Also, what if I just manually change the URL in the address bar, which is a pretty valid case for me.

Comment: If you are manually changing the URL, then also it will work. Try searching for Router events. Router has some set of events(NaviagationStart, NAvigationEnd) that will be called each time you are navigating.